# Android Kotlin JSONObject cannot be cast

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am trying to convert a JSON string into a JSON data class object. The compiler does not complain, the Android Studio 3 IDE provides the necessary hints to correct code. Still I get a runtime error saying that JSONObject cannot be cast. Please any hints...

I have the following code:

```
fun startReplay() {
    doAsync {
        triggerServerFile(eventDomain + "/get-replay-JSON.php")
        val jsonString = getServerFile(eventDomain + "/data/replay-SidR2018.json?nocache=" + Math.random())
        uiThread {
            var replayData:replayDataObject = JSONObject(jsonString) as replayDataObject
            val a= replayData.component1()
            val b= replayData.component2()[3].component3()
        }
    }
}
```

and the following data classes:

```
data class replayDataObject(
    val event: String,
    val shiptracks: List<Shiptrack>,
    val windtracks: List<Windtrack>
)

data class Shiptrack(
    val colorcode: String,
    val course: List<String>,
    val lat: List<String>,
    val lon: List<String>,
    val name: String,
    val speed: List<String>,
    val stamp: List<String>
)

data class Windtrack(
    val course: List<String>,
    val lat: List<String>,
    val lon: List<String>,
    val name: String,
    val speed: List<String>,
    val stamp: List<String>
)
```

and finally the following JSON string:

```
{
    "event": "SidR2018,Slag in de Rondte 2018",
    "shiptracks": [{
            "name": "Hollandia",
            "colorcode": "0",
            "stamp": ["1541407570", "1541407599"],
            "lat": ["53.173461666667", "53.17347"],
            "lon": ["5.409655", "5.409655"],
            "speed": ["0", "0"],
            "course": ["299", "301"]
        }, {
            "name": "Ouderzorg",
            "colorcode": "14",
            "stamp": ["1541407540", "1541407540", "1541407540"],
            "lat": ["53.17359", "53.17359", "53.17359"],
            "lon": ["5.409586", "5.409586", "5.409586"],
            "speed": ["0", "0", "0"],
            "course": ["0", "0", "0"]
        }
    ],
    "windtracks": [{
            "name": "Arcen",
            "stamp": ["1541409000", "1541411400"],
            "lat": ["51.5", "51.5"],
            "lon": ["6.2", "6.2"],
            "speed": ["4", "2"],
            "course": ["72", "61"]
        }, {
            "name": "Zeeplatform K13",
            "stamp": ["1541408400", "1541410800", "1541412000", "1541414400"],
            "lat": ["53.22", "53.22", "53.22", "53.22"],
            "lon": ["3.22", "3.22", "3.22", "3.22"],
            "speed": ["16", "16", "17", "16"],
            "course": ["126", "129", "127", "120"]
        }
    ]
}
```

The stack trace (line 381 is the line in the code containing JSOBObject:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: nl.zeilvaartwarmond.ttandroid.szwtracktrace, PID: 23370
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to nl.zeilvaartwarmond.ttandroid.szwtracktrace.MapsActivity$replayDataObject
        at nl.zeilvaartwarmond.ttandroid.szwtracktrace.MapsActivity$startReplay$1$1.invoke(MapsActivity.kt:381)
        at nl.zeilvaartwarmond.ttandroid.szwtracktrace.MapsActivity$startReplay$1$1.invoke(MapsActivity.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.anko.AsyncKt$uiThread$1.run(Async.kt:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:898)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6716)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: Post the stack trace, it'll probably tell you what can't be cast

Comment: You can't just cast a JSONObject to whatever you want. You have to manually populate a new instance of your data class with the values in the JSONObject.

Comment: Stacktrace added.

Comment: And how would I do that manually? the JSONObject function is supposed to do that...

Comment: It might be worth trying a json parser eg gson or jackson - example at https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-json-convert-data-class - would save writing a lot of boiler plate

Comment: I have been reading this: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/org/json/JSONObject, I really do not see what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: What is the source of `replayDataObject`?

Comment: As @TheWanderer already stated, the compiler has no idea how to convert from `JSONObject` to `replayDataObject`. You must by hand create a conversion function (preferably an additional constructor for `replayDataObject`) which takes the wanted data out of the `JSONObject` and calls `replayDataObject`'s primary constructor to place the data in its fields.

Comment: The replayDataObject definition is automatically generated with the IDE plugin JSONtoKotlinClass, using the JSON string given in the original question. See https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-

Comment: @Michael Butscher: It is not something the compiler has to know. The fields in the data class object are the same as in the JSON text it has to convert. So the software should read the fieldname from the JSON text and store the accompanying value in the corresponding field of the data class, during runtime.

Comment: The IDE plugin seems not to provide such functionality. I don't know which other "software" you may mean.

Comment: software = the app

Comment: @HWK the doc you are reading shows how to get data out of a json document as eg a jsonString, jsonArray etc.  It misses the other half of the work you want in mapping to a POJO, which is where gson or jackson are handy, or you could crawl the json manually and populate objects.  Hope that helps understand where the gap is.

Comment: @Rich Ackroyd, Yep, thanks mate. I start to understand it now. I removed the "as replayDataObject" from the code and checked out the replayData variable in the debugger. It now contains the JSON info, but not in the format I expected.

Comment: yeah so it should be pretty much a set of broken down json objects ?  if so you can loop around them to populate the object but I would grab a helper library, so much quicker, usually just 2 or 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You need something that interprets the `JSON` to map it to the `replayDataObject`. In Kotlin, `data class`es are very good at this using any of a number of libraries.

**Google Gson**

https://github.com/google/gson

After initializing `Gson`, you would simply take that `String`:

```
gson.fromJson(jsonString, replayDataObject::class.java)
```

Now, a word of warning, you have a lot of non-nullable types in there, and there may be issues with the data you read in, or what you expect from it.

Other libraries:

- https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon
- https://github.com/square/moshi

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit work for you.
Get json from server and convert to object.

https://square.github.io/retrofit/